# Congruence and percentage

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, percentages

Suppose I have three statements of congruence:

x = a mod n,
y = b mod m,
z = c mod p;

Furthermore, x is a given percent of x + y + z, as is y and z.

Does this uniquely determine x, y, z? Or does it at least restrict x to a predictable subset of the congruence class of a, and so on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put down all the equations and unknowns.

$ x= a +kn$, 
$ y= b +k'm$,
$ z= c +k''p$,
$ x= \alpha (x+y+z)$,
$ y= \beta (x+y+z)$,
$ z= \gamma (x+y+z)$.

I count 6 equations  and 6 unknowns so there is a chance that there is a unique solution, but as you're working with integers, there might be no solutions.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I think an appropriate choice of percentage values will be required. It is clear that we cannot have an x being 50% of (x+y) when x is congruent to 1 mod 2, and y is congruent to 0 mod 4, for example.

Provided that the percentages are possible, I think you've convinced me that a unique solution will exist.

Comment: you have to be very careful when you manipulate integers. The right way to proceed is to solve the system above and then check that the solutions are indeed acceptable (ie all the variables are integers), which is far from obvious with only those relations.

Comment: Ok. I will investigate several examples and try to gain further insight on general behavior.

Comment: I am not seeing this being solvable. I went with the following example, built to have a solution:

x = 0 mod 13; y = 0 mod 14; z = 0 mod 6.
x is 52% of the total, y is 42% of the total, z is 6% of the total.

Comment: Look up http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+[x%2Bk*n%3Da%2Cy%2Bj*n%3Db%2Cz%2Bl*n%3Dc%2Cx%3Du*%28x%2By%2Bz%29%2Cy%3Dv*%28x%2By%2Bz%29%2Cz%3Dw*%28x%2By%2Bz%29]+for+[x%2Cy%2Cz%2Ck%2Cj%2Cl]

Comment: @MattB. Note that the last three equations are not linearly independent (or rather, if they are then it forces $x=y=z=0$), so this isn't really 6 equations in 6 unknowns.  I'd imagine a generic instance would have $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$, much like the one given by Doop in the comments.

Comment: @Erick, right. What can be derived from the information presented in my recent example is a solution of x=52, y=42, z=6, but also any multiple of this set of solutions. This is obvious now.

Comment: Probably not all multiple, but definitely the lcm(n,m,p)

Comment: @ErickWong You're right, I did not put the "percentage conditions" $\alpha + \beta + \gamma =1$. Wolfram finds some interesting solutions that requires some digging to ensure they're integers. The problem is loosely related to the [Chines remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: How does this percentage condition equation help, though? The example I provided does not have a unique solution, and noting that .52 + .42 + .6 = 1 clearly does not impact this fact.

Comment: : x = 0 mod 13; y = 0 mod 14; z = 0 mod 6. x is 52% of the total, y is 42% of the total, z is 6% of the total; (x, y, z) may be (52, 42, 6), or (104, 84, 12), and so on.

Comment: @Doop The percentage conditions reduce $x,y,z$ to a 1-dimensional lattice: $(x,y,z)$ must be an integer multiple of some tuple $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ where $x_0,y_0,z_0$ have no common factor (this is essentially $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ divided by the gcd).    Say that multiple is $t$, then each of the modular constraints on $x,y,z$ can be reduced to a modular constraint on $t$ (possibly with a smaller modulus).  Then reconcile all three constraints by Chinese remaindering.